# Amstrong number return in blank result (java)

Tags: java

```
public class Amstrong {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for (int i = 100; i < 1000; i++) {

            String a = String.valueOf(i);

            int b = a.charAt(0);

            int c = a.charAt(1);

            int d = a.charAt(2);
            int e = b * b * b + c * c * c + d * d * d;

            if (e == i) {

                System.out.println(i);

            }

        }

    }

}
```

//Help me out please, no error occurred but the result returned in the blank

Comment: Using `charAt` gives you the `char` at that index, not the digit representation of that character. Meaning, `0` is not "0" but the ASCII value of the character `0`, i.e. `48`.

Answer (score 1):

You are not converting the characters to digits correctly.

One of the possible ways to fix it:

```
    int b = a.charAt(0)-'0';

    int c = a.charAt(1)-'0';

    int d = a.charAt(2)-'0';
```

Another way:

```
    int b = Character.digit (a.charAt(0),10);

    int c = Character.digit (a.charAt(1),10);

    int d = Character.digit (a.charAt(2),10);
```

Either way will give your the output:

```
153
370
371
407
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way you can do it is:

```
import java.util.*;
public class ArmstrongNumber3
{
     public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter any number");


        int n = sc.nextInt();

        int b = n;
        int sum = 0;
        int d = 0;
        while (n != 0) {
            d = n % 10;
            sum += (d * d * d);
            n = n / 10;

        }
        if (sum == b) {
            System.out.println("Armstrong");

        } else
        {
            System.out.println("Not Armstrong");
        }









    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Amstrong {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Integer num, temp, len = 0, initVal;
        double finalVal = 0;
        Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the number");
        num = scn.nextInt();
        initVal = num;
        temp = num;
        while (temp != 0) {
            temp = temp / 10;
            len++;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i <= len; i++) {
            temp = num % 10;
            finalVal = finalVal + Math.pow(temp, len);
            num = num / 10;
        }

        if (Double.valueOf(initVal) == finalVal) {
            System.out.println("Amstrong");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Not Amstrong");
        }
    }
}
```